# Java compilation error : reached end of file while parsing

Tags: java

When I compile my code I keep getting this error. Also, before i get this error, my display only showed the largest number and not the smallest one. any help will be very much appreciated. thanks for your time.

> LargestAndSmallest.java:51: reached end of file while parsing 
>     ���������
>
> ```
>   }               0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
>
>   ^ 1 error
> ```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LargestAndSmallest 
{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   { 

      int input; 

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

      System.out.print("Enter an integer number or -99 to quit: "); 
            input = keyboard.nextInt(); 

      int MIN_VALUE = 0; 
      int MAX_VALUE = 0; 

      while (input != -99) 
      { 
            if (input > MAX_VALUE) 
            { 
                 MAX_VALUE = input; 
            } 
            else if (input < MIN_VALUE) 
            { 
                 MIN_VALUE = input; 
            } 


      if (MAX_VALUE == -99)
      {
         System.out.print("\nYou did not enter any number");
      } 
      else
      {
         System.out.print("\nLargest: " + MAX_VALUE); 

         System.out.print("\nSmallest:" + MIN_VALUE);
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: It appears you are missing a closing body bracket (`}`) ?

Comment: You're missing `}` on your while-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a bracket try adding one like this

```
while (input != -99) 
      { 
            if (input > MAX_VALUE) 
            { 
                 MAX_VALUE = input; 
            } 
            else if (input < MIN_VALUE) 
            { 
                 MIN_VALUE = input; 
            }
      }
```

Comment: Ahhh ok ok i get it but now the Smallest number does not show like it does not get the smallest number and display it

Comment: it is your logic error, please do not mix in this question.  Just a hint for you: you have initial value of MIN_VALUE being 0, are you going to input anything negative? if not, 0 will keep on being the smallest value.  Choose a sensible initial value for MIN_VALUE.  And, please follow the naming convention: use minValue instead of MIN_VALUE.